# Possible missing algorithm in systemd-cryptsetup to mount a veracrypt volume

Tags: systemd, boot, cryptsetup, veracrypt

I have been trying to mount a veracrypt volume on boot on a Debian system, however systemd-cryptsetup for my volume fails with these two messages taken from this command:

```
systemctl status systemd-cryptsetup@sharedfiles.service
```

The errors:

```
PBKDF2 hash algorithm stribog512 not available, skipping.
Failed to load tcrypt superblock on /dev/sda6: Invalid argument
```

I have a strong suspicion this missing algorithm is the one the volume uses, but I'm not certain as of now. If it is, I have no idea what package I could install to provide it.

Otherwise, the "invalid argument" error could be culprit, and I provide the relevant crypttab entry here:

```
sharedfiles /dev/sda6 /dev/null tcrypt,tcrypt-veracrypt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. Found the mistake.
The password field in crypttab should not be set to /dev/null if using only a password, instead it needs to be set to none.
Fixed that, and it worked. Turns out most everything was a red herring.